# Build new domain server 2012 in parallel with existing windows domain server 2003

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I have existing network with around 400 PCs on it working under `windows xp professional` and `windows 7 professional` too.

Around 375 PCs are linked using static IP address and they are not connected to any domain server and only around 25 PCs are Linked to an existing domain server exist on the network working under `windows server 2003` be cause of project that is stopped 5 years ago and no one control what happen on it and know nothing about it so as you can see their not much think to lose.

Now I want to make new domain server
 but using `Windows Server 2012 R2`

I have installed `Windows Server 2012 R2` and I am planning to activate the `active direcory`,`DHCP`, and `DNS`
while these small number of PCs which are linked to the **OLD** `windows domain server 2003` are ruining and I want to touch them for now since they are belong to high level employees.

I want to slowly move all other PCs which are not connected to any domain server yet to join one by one with slow steps to the new domain server.

my question is

is their any conflict may happens in mt case ? if yes what is it and how I can avoid it to shift all PCs to new doamin server and keep those small number for the last step ??

if there is any advices or think you can help me with I will really appricicate since I will bulid that from the scrch

Answer (score 0):

> is their any conflict may happens

Not with Active Directory, but potentially with DHCP. You'll typically assign the DNS servers and DNS suffix to the clients with DHCP. This could lead to some DHCP clients communicating with the wrong DNS server using the wrong DNS suffix.

If, as you say, the existing client machines are using static ip addresses then this shouldn't be a problem. You can install and configure DHCP accordingly on the new Domain Controller and switch each client from static ip addressing to DHCP assigned ip addressing when you're ready to join each client to the new domain.

Comment: but they are using totally different `Active Directory` `DHCP`, and `DNS` server since the old domain server 2003 handle all these servers on his own and what I am planing to do is have  `Active Directory` `DHCP`, and `DNS`  on my new domain server 2012 R2 so why I may have conflict with the `DHCB` they are different servers... am I right on that point ?

Comment: No. DHCP is not AD specific. A DHCP server will answer any client on the network. If you have DHCP servers set up for each AD and you are assigning DNS servers and DNS suffixes for those domains then you may have clients in one domain getting DNS servers and DNS suffixes meant fopr the other domain. The DHCP doesn't know and can't differentiate between the two.

Comment: @ joeqwerty ummm it is not clear enough for me what do you mean by `DNS suffixes`...and then how to avoid that case please ... and thanks a alot for help